# Can backpressure behavior be achieved with only a readable stream

Tags: javascript, streaming

I am new to the ReadableStream API in javascript, and so far the only examples that demonstrate backpressure have used WriteableStream objects, but I want to know if the same can be done with only the ReadableStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further reading, I have found the answer - Yes.

> To use backpressure in a ReadableStream, we can ask the controller for
>   the chunk size desired by the consumer by querying the
>   ReadableStreamDefaultController.desiredSize attribute on the
>   controller. If it is too low, our ReadableStream can tell its
>   underlying source to stop sending data, and we backpressure along the
>   stream chain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Concepts